# Start Task Manager from VBScript on windows 8.1

Tags: vbscript

On windows versions prior to windows 8 my installer was using VB Script similar to this one to start task manager:

```
' StartProcessLocal.vbs
' Free example VBScript to start a process (not interactive)
' Author Guy Thomas
' Version 1.8 - December 2010
' -------------------------------------------------------' 
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, objCalc
Dim strShell, objProgram, strComputer, strExe 

strComputer = "."
strExe = "Taskmgr.exe"
' Connect to WMI
set objWMIService = getobject("winmgmts://"_
& strComputer & "/root/cimv2") 

' Obtain the Win32_Process class of object.
Set objProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")
Set objProgram = objProcess.Methods_( _
"Create").InParameters.SpawnInstance_
objProgram.CommandLine = strExe 

'Execute the program now at the command line.
Set strShell = objWMIService.ExecMethod( _
"Win32_Process", "Create", objProgram) 

WScript.echo "Created: " & strExe & " on " & strComputer
WSCript.Quit
```

This doesn't start task manager on windows 8.1.

Taskmgr.exe is in System32 directory and when I double click it it starts fine. It starts fine from command prompt: >Taskmgr.exe

In above example if you change Taskmgr.exe with Calc.exe it starts calculator. Calc.exe is also in System32 folder.

Why above script isn't starting task manager?

Comment: It seems that on windows 8.1 running task manager requires administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to start it by this way ?

```
Option Explicit
Dim Application
Application = "%windir%\system32\Taskmgr.exe"
Call RunThis(Application)
'*********************************************************************************
Sub RunThis(Application)
    Dim Ws,Result
    Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Result = Ws.Run(DblQuote(Application),1,False)
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Excellent. Do you maybe know why example code in my question requires elevated privileges and your code does not?

Comment: @VeljaRadenkovic Because you are using WMI to create the process *(which requires elevated permissions)* whereas Hackoo is using the `WScript.shell` object *(which doesn't)*.

Comment: @Lankymart `wmi` generally **does not**  require elevated permissions as the OP's code runs and creates a process e.g. with `strExe = "notepad.exe"`. There must be another cause of [Unknown failure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(v=vs.85).aspx) (`strShell.ReturnValue=8`)...

Comment: Oh ok, I always thought `Win32_Process.Create` required elevated privilege...learn something new everyday thanks @JosefZ

Comment: @JosefZ I may have been thinking of this... [Win32_Process.Create fails if user profile is not loaded](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/04/09/win32-process-create-fails-if-user-profile-is-not-loaded.aspx) *(admittedly that url is from 2008 now though)*